# How can I pass username/password to a spark job to Elasticsearch without it showing up in the sparkUI SQL tab?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have:

- An Elasticsearch instance with security enabled so that any query needs to provide a user/password.
- A Pyspark notebook that attempts to create a df and then save it to Elasticsearch.

I have found that once my job executes, in the SparkUI I can go to the SQL tab, find the ID for the save step, and after clicking on the description and then Details it shows the username and password used to connect to ES.

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
SaveIntoDataSourceCommand org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.DefaultSource@xxxxxx, Map(es.net.http.auth.user -> {username appears here}, es.net.http.auth.pass -> {password appears here}, es.port -> 9200, es.resource -> test, es.nodes -> search.test.test.com, es.spark.dataframe.write.null -> true, es.net.ssl -> true), Append
   +- LogicalRDD [count#0L, name#1], false
```

How can I avoid this from happening as I don't want users who have access to the SparkUI to see other users credentials? Is there a way to obfuscate this info in the SQL tab?

Here is what the notebook looks like.

```
##Earlier cell prompts the user for username and password once the notebook executes and then parses that into the same name variables 

%%send_to_spark -i username -t str -n username
%%send_to_spark -i password -t str -n password

columns = ["count","name"]
data = [(1, "andy"), (2, "bob"), (3, "andy")]

rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
df = rdd.toDF(columns)
df.count()
df.createGlobalTempView("df")
spark.sql("select name,sum(count) from global_temp.df group by name").show()

df.write \
        .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") \
        .mode('append') \
        .option("es.resource",                   "test") \
        .option("es.nodes",                      "search.test.test.com") \
        .option("es.port",                       9200) \
        .option("es.net.ssl",                    "true") \
        .option("es.net.http.auth.user",         username) \
        .option("es.net.http.auth.pass",         password) \
        .option("es.spark.dataframe.write.null", "true") \
        .save()
```